# How do I get the Gerudo tailor to come to Tarrey Town?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I started the Tarrey Town quest line "From the ground up" with Hudson and therefore.. [Spoilers from here]

> ..I have to look for the right people with names ending in -son. The Goron was no problem, now I am looking for the Gerudo tailor. I found Rhondson at the Kara Kara Bazar and I am fairly certain she is the vai I am looking for. But every time I talk to her, she only asks me if I am on the search for true love. How do I get her to come to Tarrey Town?

Comment: As @Ise suggested below, make sure you're not wearing the Vai (woman) costume you use to enter the Gerudo village.  You need to look like a Voe (man) to tell Rhondson about Tarrey Town

Comment: lol i did that once too! I was SOO confused! Luckily, i managed to find out what was wrong before i rage quit!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're near **Gerudo**, then I suppose you're dressed as a **Vai** (woman) ?

Because she's wondering about how she could find a **Voe** (man), so dress as a guy, and a discussion will follow in which she will judge it wouldn't be that bad to follow you.

Comment: This could very well be the reason. I didn't think about my outfit at that time. I will check and report back with the result later.

Comment: It does work. I talked to her with the Gerudo outfit, was confused why I couldn't invite her, changed back in normal clothes and then it worked.

Comment: Yup, that was the solution. Before, I visited her twice and apparently was dressed as Vai both times. I took of one part of the outfit and then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure that you're on the section of the quest where Hudson has asked you to find a Gerudo tailor.

Then, speak to Rhondson while not dressed in the Desert Vai outfit. Basically, any other set of clothes should work.